# Project Euler 14 code efficiency

Tags: python, performance

```
l = [[i, i, 1] for i in range(1,1000000)]
def collatz(li):
    for el in li:
        if el[1] == 1:
            li.remove(el)
        elif el[1] % 2 == 0:
            el[1] = el[1] / 2
            el[2] += 1
        elif el[1] % 2 == 1:
            el[1] = 3*el[1] + 1
            el[2] += 1
    return li
while len(collatz(l)) >= 2:
l = collatz(l)

print l
```

Hi, this is a (partial) solution to [Euler problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14), written in Python.

> ### Longest Collatz sequence
>
> #### Problem 14
>
> The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive integers:
>
> ```
> n → n/2 (n is even)
> n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
> ```
>
> Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following sequence:
>
> ```
> 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
> ```
>
> It can be seen that this sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1) contains 10 terms. Although it has not been proved yet (Collatz Problem), it is thought that all starting numbers finish at 1.
>
> Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?
>
> **NOTE:** Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one million.

I wrote partial because it does not really output the solution since I can't really run it in the whole 1 - 1000000 range. It's way too slow - taking more than 20 minutes the last time I killed the process. I have barely just started with python and programming in general (about 2 weeks) and I am looking to understand what's the obvious mistake I am making in terms of efficiency. I googled some solutions and even the average ones are orders of magnitude faster than mine. So what am I missing here? Any pointers to literature to avoid making the same mistakes in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you use brute force algorithm that is inefficient.this is my solution to problem 14 from project Euler. it takes a few second to run. the key is you should save previous results in a dictionary so you don't have to compute those results again.:

```
#problem 14 project euler
import time
start=time.time()
has2={}
def collatz(x):
    seq=[]
    seq.append(x)
    temp=x
    while(temp>1):
        if temp%2==0:
            temp=int(temp/2)
            if temp in has2:
                seq+=has2[temp]
                break
            else:
                seq.append(temp)
        else:
            temp=3*temp+1
            if temp in has2:
                seq+=has2[temp]
                break
            else:
                seq.append(temp)


    has2[x]=seq            
    return len(seq)

num=0
greatest=0
for i in range(1000000):
    c=collatz(i)
    if num<c:
        num=c
        greatest=i
print('{0} has {1} elements. calculation time ={2} seconds.'.format(greatest,num,time.time()-start))
```

Comment: I like this answer because it's non-recursive. +1 for that

Answer (score 2):

a little improvement upon sara's answer

```
import time
start = time.time()

def collatz(n):
    k = n
    length = 1
    nList = []
    nList.append(n)
    while n != 1:
        if n not in dic:
            n = collatzRule(n)
            nList.append(n)
            length += 1
        else:
            # we dont need the values but we do need the real length for the for-loop
            nList.extend([None for _ in range(dic[n] - 1)])
            length = (length - 1) + dic[n]
            break

    for seq in nList:
        if seq not in dic:
            dic[seq] = len(nList) - nList.index(seq)

    return length

def collatzRule(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n // 2
    else:
        return 3 * n + 1

longestLen = 0
longestNum = 0
dic = {}

for n in range(2, 1000001):
    prsntLen = collatz(n)
    if prsntLen > longestLen:
        longestLen = prsntLen
        longestNum = n
    # print(f'{n}: {prsntLen}')

print(f'The starting num is: {longestNum} with the longest chain having: {longestLen} terms.')
print(f'time taken: {time.time() - start}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sara's answer is great, but can be more efficient.
If the value we return from the function is `len(seq)`, why not just counting the number of iterations instead of conducting a list first?

I have changed the code slightly, and the performance improvement is significant

```
def collatz(x):
    count = 1
    temp = x  
    while temp > 1:
        if temp % 2 == 0:
            temp = int(temp/2)
            if temp in has2:  # calculate temp and check if in cache
                count += has2[temp]
                break
            else:
                count += 1
        else:
            temp = 3*temp + 1
            if temp in has2:            
                count += has2[temp]
                break
            else:
                count += 1

    has2[x] = count
    return count

837799 has 525 elements. calculation time =1.97099995613 seconds.
```

Compared to the original version 
`837799 has 525 elements. calculation time =11.3389999866 seconds.`

Using list of `int` rather than building the whole list is **~80% faster.**

Comment: It's all good but your code adds 1 to true answer of how many steps there are.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sara says you could use dictionary to save previous results and then look them up for making program run faster. But I don't quite understand your results, taking more than 20 mins sounds like you have some problem.
By using bruteforce i get code to run about at 16 sec.

```
#!/bin/python3
########################
# Collatz Conjecture   #
# Written by jeb 2015  #
########################
import time


current = 0
high = 0

# While number is not one, either divide it by 2
# or multiply with 3 and add one
# Returns number of iterations
def NonRecursiveCollatz(i):
    counter = 1
    while i != 1:
        counter = counter + 1
        if i%2 == 0:
            i = i / 2
        else:
            i = 3*i + 1
    return counter


time_start = time.time()

# Test all numbers between 1 and 1.000.000
# If number returned is higher than last one, store it nd remember
# what number we used as input to the function
for i in range(1,1000000):
current = NonRecursiveCollatz(i)
if current > high:
    high = current
    number = i


elapsed_time = time.time() - time_start

print "Highest chain"
print high
print "From number "
print number
print "Time taken " 
print elapsed_time
```

With the output:

```
Highest chain
525
From number 
837799
Time taken 
16.730340004
```

Comment: Can the fact that only one of the eight cores (of my i7) is used by python? Or does it take too long even with this in mind?

Comment: I think it still is too long, have you tried running my code?

Comment: But if you don't get better performance, why don't you use/implement the dictionary/look-up solution instead?

Comment: I will, but right now that you brought it up, understanding what might be wrong with my pc or os seems a more pressing issue. Is your algorithm supposed to be much faster than mine?

Comment: Despite being much faster than mine, you algorithm still takes 58 seconds on my computer. What are you pc's specs? This is quite strange

Answer (score -1):

```
//Longest Colletz Sequence
public class Problem14 {
    static long getLength(long numb) {
        long length = 0;
        for(long i=numb; i>=1;) {
            length++;
            if(i==1)
                break;
            if(i%2==0)
                i = i/2;
            else
                i = (3*i)+1;
        }
        return length;
    }
    static void solution(long numb) {
        long number = numb;
        long maxLength = getLength(number);
        for(long i=numb; i>=1; i--) {
            if(getLength(i)>=maxLength) {
                maxLength = getLength(i);
                number = i;
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("`enter code here`Length of "+number+" is : "+maxLength);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        solution(1000000);  
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time : "+(end-begin));
    }
}

output :
Length of 837799 is : 525
Time : 502
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65252784/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider adding some explanations to answer.